# Location header with IDN characters broken when hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

For some POST calls in our API we point the response Location header to the created resource.

The Location header can contain a URL with IDN characters (e.g. `http://résponse.com`)

When hosting the API in IIS, IIS changes the Location header to `http://rÃ©sponse.com/`

There is definitely something wrong in the encoding there.
When we make our API self-hosted, the Location header isn't touched.
Is there some setting I'm missing in IIS that causes this behavior?
The content type charset is set to utf-8, but this is already the default in IIS I guess.

Version of IIS is 8.5+
We use Web API, but using NancyFx causes the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just puny encoded the special characters for now,
but I still don't understand why IIS changes the header and a self-hosted solution doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the header to the HTTP Response Headers list for that site. If none is specified, it will be delivered in whatever the user agent requests, which is likely why you're seeing the ISO-8859-1

"Properties" => "HTTP Headers" => "File Types..." => "New Type...". Put in the extension you want to map, separately for each extension; IIS users will probably want to map .htm, .html,... Then, for Content type, add "text/html;charset=utf-8" (without the quotes; substitute your desired charset for utf-8;

Answer (score 0):

Set the encoding and culture configuration in .Net Globalization feature in IIS (I assume you are hosting a asp.net based API?)